# Lambda, sort key addition causes failure

Tags: aws-lambda

I have the following Lambda function that I am using the query DynamoDB:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):

    #query vars
    coursenameVar = event['query']['coursenameVar']
    lessonVar = event['query']['lessonVar']

    # make the connection to dynamodb
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')

    # select the table
    table = dynamodb.Table("testai")

    # query and response
    response = table.query(
    KeyConditionExpression=Key('coursename').eq(coursenameVar) & Key('lesson').eq(lessonVar))
    data = response['Items']
    return data
```

The DB table has two keys:

```
Primary partition key   coursename (String)
Primary sort key    lesson (Number)
```

The function is simple; it takes two query parameters from the URL via API Gateway and uses those as KeyConditionExpression keys for the query as follows:

```
KeyConditionExpression=Key('coursename').eq(coursenameVar) & Key('lesson').eq(lessonVar))
```

The problem:

Everything work as needed as long as I am only using the primary partition key in the query like this:

```
KeyConditionExpression=Key('coursename').eq(coursenameVar)
```

But as soon as I add the sort key like this:

```
KeyConditionExpression=Key('coursename').eq(coursenameVar) & Key('lesson').eq(lessonVar))
```

I get the following error:

```
  "errorMessage": "An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: One or more parameter values were invalid: Condition parameter type does not match schema type",
  "errorType": "ClientError",
```

Note: my sort key is numeric - am I missing a type declaration somewhere? Any other thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might need to convert the lessonVar field from a string to an integer, like so:

```
Key('lesson').eq(int(lessonVar)))
```

Comment: That removed the error, but now my response is empty, which leads me to believe the params arent being passed now.

Comment: Add some logging to see what the param values are then. Also, attempt the same query in the AWS DynamoDB console to verify there should be a response.

Comment: Add some logging. You need to be able to do some basic debugging to figure out issues like this. For example log `lessonVar` value as well as `int(lessonVar)` value to verify the values look correct that you are passing to the query.